# C++ array initialization

Tags: c++, arrays, initialization

Why can’t I initialize a local array with a string

Comment: Give us the code, it might make the question a bit clearer.

Comment: Do you mean to ask: "Why can't I initialize a local array **from** a string?"

Answer (score 7):

> Why can’t I initialize a local array with a string

The correct answer is that you can – for a given definition of array, and string. What exactly do you want to achieve?

```
char str[] = "Hello world";
```

Comment: this would better be "const char str[]".  Otherwise you may end up writing into the executable bytes.

Comment: @xtofl: No. In the above code, the constant string literal is *copied* into a writable memory location. The code is safe and `str` may safely be manipulated. You would be right if I had used a pointer instead of an array.

Answer (score 4):

The question is very skinny on details but:

```
char arr[] = {'a','b','c', 0};
```

or

```
char arr[] = "string";
```

**EDIT**:

In response to questions:

```
char s1[] = "hi";
char s2[] = {'h','i',0};
memcpy(s1, "by", sizeof(s1));
memcpy(s2, "by", sizeof(s2));
cout << ios::hex << &s1 << endl;
cout << ios::hex << &s2 << endl;
cout << s1 << endl;
cout << s2 << endl;
```

Prints:

```
80xbfffed72
80xbfffed6f
by
by
```

At least on my system it looks like both are allocated in the same memory space, I don't see any problems or differences. C for example defines `string` as a null terminated char array - I believe this is the same in C++, not to be confused with `std::string`.

Comment: These are not equivalent: the latter form allows you to e.g. memset( arr, 0, 7), and thus change your executable's data segment.

Comment: @xtofl:  Can you go into that in more detail?  I'm pretty sure that both of these are equivalent.  It would be different if the second was "const char * arr=", but it isn't, and I'm pretty sure that a quoted string is just a special syntax for an aggregate initializer, and so the behaviour should be identical.

Answer (score 1):

```
std::vector<std::string> abc(5,"abc");
```

will create a vector with 5 elements initialized to "abc".